# How to overflow a shadow from a fixed Height container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866149/how-to-cast-a-shadow-over-component-bounds) that the `DropShadows` can't overflow over component with a fixed `Height`.

I tried to add somme `ClipToBounds="False"` in every containers but it doesn't seems to work.

you will see the problem if you create a new project with this code :

```
<Window .... >
    <StackPanel x:Name="Sp2" Margin="20" Height="47" ClipToBounds="False">
        <Rectangle Height="40" Fill="Purple" Margin="4" ClipToBounds="False">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Opacity=".4" BlurRadius="13" ShadowDepth="4" Direction="288"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem :
[image]
On the left that's what i want, a shadow overflowing on a fixed height component, and on the right that's what i have.

As I work in a team and I'm developping every UI components for our application and I'd like other people of my team not to have to pay attention to these kind of details. How can we avoid this behavior, and if we can't what would be the guidelines to avoid this clipping effect ?

Comment: Is it still [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53866149/1997232)? Or a new problem? In any case consider to add something to demonstrate the problem: code, xaml, screenshots (how it is and what you want instead).

Comment: @Sinatr Woops sorry, i forgot to add the code section, my bad, i edited the post

Comment: What should I look at when using your xaml? Can you explain in words what is wrong or (better) make a screenshot?

Comment: @Sinatr Here is the screenshot :)

Comment: In other words if I remove one of the parent containers (`StackPanel` is easier) it works (the shadow is not clipped). You have to work on your [mcve] skills a bit, using `<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="30" />` is much easier to see ;)

Comment: And as for why - the nature of effects in wpf I guess, the shader only receive parent container at maximum and its limited to draw inside it. See [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825099/1997232) or you can use "floating overlap technique": have `Rectangle` on the higher level (same as `StackPanel`) and use bindings in the view to position rectangle as if it was inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override GetLayoutClip() to stop most things clipping.

As explained here.

http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/12/28/cliptoboundsmaybe/

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace wpf_99
{
public class NoClipStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
    {
        return ClipToBounds ? base.GetLayoutClip(layoutSlotSize) : null;
    }
    }
}
```

Markup

```
<Grid>
    <local:NoClipStackPanel x:Name="Sp2" Margin="20" Height="47" ClipToBounds="False">
        <Rectangle Height="40" Fill="Purple" Margin="4" ClipToBounds="False">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Opacity=".4" BlurRadius="13" ShadowDepth="4" Direction="288"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
    </local:NoClipStackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to solve this issue is similar to solution of another problem, when trying to apply effects to control containing text and text become blurred. The idea is to *detach* effect, by applying it to something else, while ensuring that visually it looks like effect was applied to where you need it.

In your case you can do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=rect}"
               Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=rect}"
               Fill="Green">
        <Rectangle.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="30" />
        </Rectangle.Effect>
    </Rectangle>
    <StackPanel Margin="20" Height="47">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Height="40" Fill="Purple" Margin="4">

            <!-- remove effect from here -->

        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The effect is not anymore on nested rectangle, but on some element (I've used `Rectangle`) which is added below `StackPanel` (since its transparent) in visual tree. If you do it like this than shadow can now extend itself to whole grid (which takes whole window size).